# PDF/postscript or HTML to ZPL(Zebra Printing Language) code

Tags: postscript, zebra-printers, zpl

I have a pdf file or the post-script file of that pdf. My Requirement is to convert this file to ZPL code so that my thermal printer can print that.
I searched a lot on google but not able to find any solution which can meet my requirements.
Please suggest any way forward if you encountered this situation before.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

First, convert the PDF to a bitmap.  Then convert the bitmap to a base 64 string.

Then use ZPL to store the image temporarily on the printer:

```
~DGR:FILENAME.GRF,2261,17,:Z64:YOURBMPSTRING
```

Then send ZPL that recalls the image:

```
^XA
^XGR:FILENAME.GRF,1,1^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y
^XZ
```

Then send code to cleanup the image:

```
^XA
^IDR:FILENAME.GRF
^XZ
```

You can send the ZPL all at once, I just broke it out here to show each step.  The [ZPL Manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) has more details about the commands used. You might want to read up on ^DG ^XG ^ID.  Also, there is a section on base 64 encoding at the end of the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to purchase a license from Zebra for a Virtual Device that supports printing PDF directly to the printer.  Not all printers are supported, but here is a [link to more information and a spec sheet](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/link-os/pdf-virtual-device.html):

Answer (score 0):

There is a way you could go which can do this. If you have postscript as you say,
then you can interface the postscript operators to capture the output.

This involves quite a bit of programming. The idea is described in the [Camelot Paper](http://www.planetpdf.com/planetpdf/pdfs/warnock_camelot.pdf).

Comment: If you have the specification for ZPL (whatever that is) you could write a Ghostscript device too, its probably easier.